# Store remote PDF to Android Internal Storage

Tags: android

In my app I want to store a remote pdf to internal storage, so that no other application will have access to it. Can anyone please help.
Thanks in advance.

My code to store pdf file is :

```
            File newdir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),"/n.pdf");
            newdir.mkdirs();
            try {

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newdir);
                URL url = new URL("my_pdf_path");
                urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream input = url.openStream();

                 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    input.close();



            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

And when I try to access the above path, it says : "Error opening file. It does not exist or cannot be read".

Answer (score 0):

You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal for full details. Read the answer to this question for a java example of how to download the file from the web. [Android - downloading image from web, saving to internal memory in location private to app, displaying for list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181566/android-downloading-image-from-web-saving-to-internal-memory-in-location-priv)

Comment: Thanks you very much for the quick reply. It worked. One more help: I tried to access the above stored pdf through intent. But showed the same "Error opening file. It does not exist or cannot be read".